# Transactional email templating syntax - calling a helper or model method and assign to variable

Tags: email, sales

In the email templating syntax.  Is it possible to assign a return value of a magento helper to a variable?

For example this would be perfect:

```
{{var myVar = helper(myhelper).helperMethod }}
```

i.e. i want to assign the return value of a helper method to a variable in the template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can include the output of **any** block into the shipping email via the following:

```
{{block type="yourcustom/shippingblock" template="path/to/your/template.phtml"}}
```

IIRC your block must extend `Mage_Core_Block_Template`.  To get ahold of the current shipment information in your block use the following:

```
$shipment = Mage::registry('current_shipment');
```

Since patch SUPEE-6788 or Magento 1.9.2.2 block which are used in the email templates or in CMS pages need to be white listed. See [How can i add block to whitelist?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89213/how-can-i-add-block-to-whitelist)

Comment: I'll leave this answer, but for some reason @axel's answer wasn't displaying here when I posted.

Comment: I think my question is missleading.  I will edit the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 2):

You can include blocks into the email templates, using the standard CMS block code.

For example:

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/my_email_block.phtml' order=$order shipment=$shipment }}
```

Then in the template file `email/my_email_block.phtml`

-> You can access the **Shipment** object by using `$this->getShipment()`.
-> You can access the **Order** object by using `$this->getOrder()`.

Comment: Unfortunately i need it assigned to a template variable.

Comment: What do you mean `assigned to a template variable?`  Can you provide what you've done so far (the methods you took to add the new property to the shipment object), and the intended output in the email?

Comment: I mean in the template there are a list of variables available using the syntax {{var theVariable}}  later in the sendTransactional method of Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template these variables get passed.  I need to access them at this point so it must be variable on the email template.