# How to add new Template Variable in magento

Tags: magento-enterprise, email, magento-1, transactional-mail, variables

I want to add new template variable and use it in transactional email template from backend. Same as "Confirmation URL". Please refer to screen shot:

[image]

Thanks!!!

Comment: Maybe this can help : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45754/how-can-an-extension-add-transactional-email-variables-available-in-email-temp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template variables are comes from email template comments, To add new template variable we need to add it to email template comment section(at top of email template html) as like below:

```
<!--@subject Welcome, {{var customer.name}}! @-->
<!--@vars
{"store url=\"\"":"Store Url",
"var logo_url":"Email Logo Image Url",
"htmlescape var=$customer.name":"Customer Name",
"store url=\"customer/account/\"":"Customer Account Url",
"var customer.email":"Customer Email",
"reset password url=\"customer/account/resetpassword/\" _query_id=$customer.id _query_token=$customer.rp_token":"Reset Password URL",
"htmlescape var=$customer.password":"Customer Password"}
@-->
```

It automatically load the template variables in transactional email template variables.

Comment: How to add website id and apply if-else condition on that? Thanks @Ranjit Shinde

Answer (score 2):

You add custom variables by accessing **System > Custom Variables** menu.

[image]

Comment: thanks for answer but i want add link something like this :` {{store url="customer/account/confirm/" _query_id=$customer.id _query_key=$customer.confirmation _query_back_url=$back_url}} ` and custom variables are not accepting `$customer`

Answer (score 0):

To add new custom variable:

- Go to **System** >> **Custom Variables**.
- Click on **Add New Variable** button.
- Fill in values for **Variable Code**, **Variable Name**, **Variable HTML Value**, **Variable Plain Value** and click on **Save** button.

Now you can use this new variable in transactional emails, cms pages, cms blocks and other places where you are able to place default variables.

Comment: thanks for answer but i want add link something like this :` {{store url="customer/account/confirm/" _query_id=$customer.id _query_key=$customer.confirmation _query_back_url=$back_url}} ` and custom variables are not accepting `$customer`

Comment: How to add website id and apply if-else condition on that? Thanks @Mohit Kumar Arora