# How to increase the {{var qty}} digits ? 1 to 000001

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, qty-increment

I need increase, Magento default {{var qty}} is like 1 or 10 or 100. now i want to increase the digits purchased qty 1 means = 000001 and same for 10= 000010 for 100 = 000100 need to add 0's in front on EMAIL TEMPLATE only.
Need to increase the digits. please help ! thanks in advance

Comment: you can use `printf('%06d', $id);` to add leading zeroes

Comment: @Anja It's not possible to add PHP code inside the mail template ...

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no easy possibility for this. You could add an own email template directive to accomplish that as described here:

[How can an extension add transactional email variables? (available in email templates)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45754/how-can-an-extension-add-transactional-email-variables-available-in-email-temp)

The directive would simply contain Anja's code (`printf('%06d', $qty);`)

Comment: I cannot understand , on that link can you explain me, How can i get it so?

Comment: Is any possible to assign a new variable for email template. i need this for only one email . not for all the email template.  please guide me how can i create new custom variable to get the qty and which file have to add the custom code to get the all qty.

Comment: as anyone knows, how can i get it? please help me.

Comment: It is described pretty well in the link I provided - how far did you come?