# How can i add block to whitelist?

Tags: magento-1.9, whitelist

Looking in this community i found that i can whitelist block in `System > Permissions > Blocks`.

My problem is that i do not have `System > Permissions > Blocks` in my admin panel.

I have only `System > Permissions > Users` and `System > Permissions > Roles`

Can you give me any advice why i do not see `System > Permissions > Blocks` ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Have you applied the latest SUPEE-6788 patch? This is what creates the whitelisting system.

If you did install the patch, make sure you clear the Magento cache so the table gets created and the feature is enabled. Then you should be able to whitelist blocks and vars.

Comment: Okey, thank you